# Rotate x-axis tick labels when don't know x-axis value variable

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I am trying to plot the following dataframe, and then rotate x-axis labels

```
index   label_h1    label_h2    label_h3    
d1  1.2     2.00    0.0     
d2  5.3     4.00    0.2 
d3  7.00    145.00  4.00
```

plot code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(13,10), dpi= 80)
sns.boxplot(data=df)
plt.yscale("log") 
plt.show()
```

If I try to rotate labels

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_xticklabels(df.columns,rotation = 90)
```

I get the error:

```
UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator
  ax.set_xticklabels(df_corr.columns,rotation = 90)
```

How can I rotate the labels when plotting a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set x ticks labels with `df_corr.columns` you are using data's columns, which are 4 (`'index'`, `'label_h1'`, `'label_h2'`, `'label_h3'`), for only three boxes, so you should discard `'index'` column:

```
ax.set_xticklabels([label for label in df.columns if label != 'index'],rotation = 90)
```

In alternative, as explained by Jody Klymak in the comment below, you can use a easier way with:

```
ax.tick_params(which='major', labelrotation=90)
```

### Complete code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv(r'data/data.csv')


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(13,10), dpi= 80)

sns.boxplot(data=df, ax = ax)

ax.tick_params(which='major', labelrotation=90)
ax.set_yscale("log") 

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Don't loop trough the ticks.  `ax.tick_params(which='x', labelrotation=90)` is _far_ easier and will continue to work even if more is added to the plot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, edited my answer accordingly. Just a note: `'x'` is not a valid value for `which` parameter; supported values are `'major'`, `'minor'`, `'both'`.

Comment: Sorry, `axis='x'` https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html